# xml unexpected token error in android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I try parsing xml received the following error:
"unexpected token error"

here myxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <records>   
        <record date="11/12">
            <profile>
                <name>john</name>
                <sex>male</sex>
                <age>18</age>
            </profile>
            <profile>
                <name>bill</name>
                <sex>male</sex>
                <age>20</age>
            </profile>
            <profile>
                <name>jully</name>
                <sex>female</sex>
                <age>22</age>
            </profile>
        </record>
    </records>
```

and xml parsing code

```
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(ist, "UTF-8")));
```

xml file is wrong? or...
help would be appreciated

Comment: can You post stack trace?

Comment: Chances are that the xml file is not in proper utf-8, but still stack trace would be useful to ascertain that.

Answer (score 0):

It might depends on the parser as well. I think there is a relate question [KXmlParser throws "Unexpected token" exception at the start of RSS pasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254089/kxmlparser-throws-unexpected-token-exception-at-the-start-of-rss-pasing) :

Quoting [vmironov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1950649/vmironov)'s answer:

So one reason might be that the xml file doesn't actually start with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>.` It starts with three special bytes `EF BB BF` which are [Byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

`InputStreamReader`( Which you are using here) doesn't handle these bytes automatically, so you have to handle them manually. The simplest way to it is to use `BOMInpustStream` available in`Commons IO` library.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your XML File is pretty fine.

But, if the xml is in a File ... Why don't you use 'FileInputStream' intead of 'InputSource'?:

```
        Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(xmlFile) );
```

By the way, I'm goint to put here a small App that do whatyou wish and doesn't crash.  It creates your xml file in the SDCArd, and then it sucesfully reads that xml and build the 'Document' object:

```
package com.example.xmlt;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public static String MYDIRECTORY = "MyDirectory";

    public static String FILENAME = "file1.xml";

    public static String XMLCONTENT =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"+
            "<records>\n"+
                "<record date=\"11/12\">\n"+
                    "<profile>\n"+
                        "<name>john</name>\n"+
                        "<sex>male</sex>\n"+
                        "<age>18</age>\n"+
                    "</profile>\n"+
                    "<profile>\n"+
                        "<name>bill</name>\n"+
                        "<sex>male</sex>\n"+
                        "<age>20</age>\n"+
                    "</profile>\n"+
                    "<profile>\n"+
                        "<name>jully</name>\n"+
                        "<sex>female</sex>\n"+
                        "<age>22</age>\n"+
                    "</profile>\n"+
               "</record>\n"+
            "</records>\n";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try{

            File xmlFile = createFile(getApplicationContext(),FILENAME,XMLCONTENT);

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(xmlFile) );

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    private static File createFile(Context context, String filename, String fileContent)
            throws  FileNotFoundException, IOException{

        String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File f1 = new File( baseDir+ "/"+ MYDIRECTORY +"/");
        f1.mkdirs();

        File f2 = new File( baseDir+ "/"+ MYDIRECTORY +"/" + filename);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f2);
        outputStream.write(fileContent.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
        return f2;
    }
}
```